# Use of getattr on a class with data descriptor

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, getattr

While using data descriptors in building classes, I came across a strange behavior of getattr function on a class.

```
# this is a data descriptor
class String(object):
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        pass
    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        pass

# This defines a class A with 'dot' notation support for attribute 'a'
class A(object):
    a = String()

obj = A()
assert getattr(A, 'a') is A.__dict__['a']
# This raises AssertionError
```

LHS return an empty string, while the RHS returns an instance of `String`. I thought `getattr` on an object was to get the value for the key inside the `__dict__`. How does `getattr` function work on a class object?

Comment: Are you sure that it returns an empty string and not `None`?

Comment: *LHS return an empty string* Sure? As I am trying, it returns `None`. And why shouldn't it? You tell it so in the descriptor!

Comment: BTW: `A.a` is **not** the same as `A.__dict__['a']`. Only the first triggers "the whole attribute mechanism".

Comment: So `getattr(obj, 'a')` and getattr(A, 'a')` are somewhat similar? It turns out the descriptor had a default value of '' set in my case.
So the only way to recover the descriptor object is to inspect the class' `__dict__` directly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getattr(A, 'a')` triggers the descriptor protocol, even on classes, so `String.__get__(None, A)` is called.

That returns `None` because your `String.__get__()` method has no explicit `return` statement.

From the [*Descriptor Howto*](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#invoking-descriptors):

> For classes, the machinery is in `type.__getattribute__()` which transforms `B.x` into `B.__dict__['x'].__get__(None, B)`.

`getattr(A, 'a')` is just a dynamic from of `A.a` here, so `A.__dict__['x'].__get__(None, A)` is executed, which is why you don't get the same thing as `A.__dict__['x']`.

If you expected it to return the descriptor object itself, you'll have to do so *explicitly*; `instance` will be set to `None` in that case:

```
class String(object):
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        if instance is None:
            return self
    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        pass
```

This is what the `property` descriptor object does.

Note that the `owner` argument to `descriptor.__get__` is optional; if not set you are supposed to use `type(instance)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

`getattr(A, 'a')` is the same as `A.a`. This calls the respective descriptor, if present. So it provides the value presented by the descriptor, which is `None`.